# Applying the Bayes Theorem Correctly

Tags: probability

Here are the questions:

A Human Resources Manager has a lifelong experience of interviewing applicants for jobs in the IT field and he has at least +2 standard deviations more common sense than the ordinary HR employee, which is still not that much, but it should account for something.

This "abundance" of common sense gives him a 95% certainty to divide applicants correctly into these two categories: "suitable" and "unsuitable"

He also assumes that 90% of all applicants are suitable for their desired job position.

Because this manager is not so good with numbers and probabilities, he wants to know what the probability is of him deciding that an applicant is unsuitable, given that the applicant IS in fact suitable. And he also wants to know the probability of an applicant being in fact unsuitable, after he's told him that he's unsuitable.

The way I would solve the first question, which basically asks for P(BC|A):

P(A)    = applicant is in fact suitable = 0.9
P(AC)   = applicant is in fact unsuitable = 0.1

P(B|A)  = Decision suitable, given a suitable applicant in the first place = 0.95
P(B|AC) = Decision suitable, given an unsuitable applicant in the first place = 0.05

P(BC|A) = Decision unsuitable, given a suitable applicant in the first place = 0.05
P(BC|AC)= Decision usuitable, given an unsuitable applicant in the first place = 0.95

If I haven't made any mistakes, shouldn't the answer to the first question equal 0.05 = 5%?

Second question (P(AC|BC)=?):

Bayes: P(AC|BC) = P(BC|AC) * (P(AC)/P(BC)) = $(0.95\times0.1)/(0.95\times0.1 + 0.05\times0.9)=0.678=67.8\%$

I'm sure I made a mistake somewhere, I just don't know where. Your help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your answer.  Better notated answer would be below:

DU = Deciding Unsuitable

DS = Deciding Suitable

S = Suitable

U = Unsuitable

$$P(DS/S) = 0.95$$
$$P(DU/U) = 0.95$$
$$P(DU/S) = 0.05$$
$$P(DS/U) = 0.05$$
$$P(S) = 0.9$$
$$P(U) = 0.1$$

Part I = P(DU/S) = 0.05

Part II =>

$$P(U/DU) = \dfrac{P(DU/U)\times P(U)}{P(DU/U)\times P(U)+P(DU/S)\times P(S)}$$
$$P(U/DU) = \dfrac{0.95\times0.1}{0.95\times0.1+0.05\times0.9} = 0.678$$

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation & clearer structuring, Satish!